# Check for role in node-type.tpl.php

Tags: drupal

Is there any way to check the role of the viewer within a drupal theme file, so as to write a conditional statement?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current user is always available as a global variable, so just do:

```
// Make the user object available
global $user;
// Grab the user roles
$roles = $user->roles;
```

$user->roles will be an array of role names, keyed by role id (rid).

---

Edit: To be precise, the global user object is made available during early bootstrapping, in phase `DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION`, but from the point of custom coding within themes or modules, you can treat that global as always available.

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
 
  global $user;
  $num_roles = db_fetch_object(pager_query(db_rewrite_sql('SELECT rid from {role} ORDER BY rid Desc')))->rid;  // Find how many roles are there
  for($i=0; $i < $num_roles; $i++){
      if(strlen($user->roles[$i]) >0){
        echo $user->roles[$i];
        $i = $num_roles;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an appendix to Henrik Opel's answer:
if you use it in a tpl.php file, then create a variable first in a preprocess_node function:

```
<?php
function YOURTEMPLATE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  $variables['current_user_roles'] = $user->roles;
}
?>
```

Now you can print your roles in your tpl.php:

```
<?php
if ($current_user_roles) {
?>
<ul class="roles">
<?php
  foreach ($current_user_roles as $role) {
    ?><li class="roles-item"><?php print $role; ?></li><?php
  }
?>
</ul>
```